# Find and replace list value in a dictionary python 3

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I'm new to python. I'm trying to find and remove duplicate list values from the dictionary below:

`dict =  {'happy':['sun', 'moon', 'bills' 'chocolate'], 'sad':['fail', 'test', 'bills', 'baloon'], 'random': ['baloon', 'france', 'sun'] }`

I want the dictionary dictionary to look like this after removing the duplicates from the list

`expectd_dict = {'happy':['sun', 'moon', 'chocolate', 'bills'], 'sad':['fail', 'test','baloon'], 'random': ['france] }`

I have looked for solutions on the internet but to no avail. I have tried creating an empty list and dict, iterating through the dictionary key and value, and also iterating through the list values, then adding it the to the empty list if not present, but I don't seem to be getting the desired result.

```
output_dict = {}
output_list = []
for key, value in d.items():
    if key not in output_dict.values():
        for i in value:
            if i not in output_list:
            output_list.append(i)
            output_dict[key] = output_list
print(output_dict)
```

Comment: You need to explain what takes key takes priority in having a certain value, i.e, why does `sad` have `bills` and not `happy` when `happy` also has `bills` as a duplicate?

Comment: Adding on to the previous comment, why is `bills` removed from `happy` but kept in `sad`. Similarly why is `baloon` kept in sad but removed from `random`?

Comment: Sorry I have updated the question. The top keys take priority. If a value exist in `happy` and `sad`, the duplicate value should be removed from `sad`. Likewise, if a value exist in `sad` and `random`, the duplicate value should be removed from  `random`

Comment: then why your expected output have `baloon` in `random` and not in `sad`?

Answer (score 0):

Think you want process lists in the order 'happy' -> 'random' -> 'sad'.
Loop in the list values, check if it seen in previous action, if not found, add it to the final list, add it to `seen_values`.

```
seen_values = set()
for key in ('happy', 'random', 'sad'):
    final_list = []
    for value in dict[key]:
        if value in seen_values:
            continue
        seen_values.add(value)
        final_list.append(value)
    dict[key] = final_list
```